# How can i update a value that comes from router in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router

so im facing an issue where i need to update values in a table which are pushed from another component through router.push from nextJS, and it is working as expected, but i want to update the values that are passed through the router

```
setValues(values.map(x => {
      return x.id == uniqueId 
       ? {
           ...x,
           debt: res.data.debt
         }
       : x;
    })
```

and when i update my state original values, it correctly renders its new values , but nothing happens to the routed values stored in the same state, anyone has tried a method to also render the 'routed' with new values?,

any help or idea will be much appreciated

Comment: _"i want to update the values that are passed through the router"_ - Do you mean you want to change the values of the `router` instance directly? Why would you want to do that? You should only be manipulating the state values.

Comment: i tried changing the state as stated above, but for example
const router = useRouter()
const { value, value2 } = router.query

neither value or value2 show changes when i update the state that holds their value, maybe there is another way to do what i want and i may not have to use the router instance, if thats the case, do you know any other possible way? thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to update what's passed in the router, then you need to route with the values from the new state using `router.push`.